# Using modify->reword for commit change in EGit/Eclipse and what to do next?

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a coworker who is working on a branch called GL104.  He made two commits and pushed those to the repository.  The newest commit is faed3fd7 on the repos.  He then realized he wanted to change his commit message, so he pulled it up in History, right-clicked on the newest commit and selected Modify->Reword.  He changed his text and this gave him a new commit ID.  He did not do a "Push Commit" or push of any kind to the server.  His "status" for the project then showed him being ahead by 2 commits.  I suggested he push his local branch up to the repos but it was rejected for non-fast-forward.  After that his status showed him being ahead by 1 commit, behind by 1 commit.  I don't understand why this is.

Anyway, I'm trying to find this on the net as I type but not finding anything yet.  So what is the proper procedure here?  I'm guessing he has to push his reworded commit.  I'm not sure.

We are using Eclipse Mars.1

Answer (score 1):

Once you push a commit, you normally cannot change the commit message. That is because behind the scenes, when you select "Reword" a new commit is created with the same parent as the old commit. When you have two commits with the same parent, a merge is required; that is why it is not letting you push the new commit.

Now, if nobody else has done a pull on the misworded commit, you can do a force push (`git push -f`) which will get rid of that commit and replace it with the correct one. But if anyone else *has* already pulled that misworded commit to their local repo, the force push will simply delay the merging from happening (i.e. when that other person does the next pull).

So, long story short, your coworker is probably best off just leaving the commit as is.

Comment: It's just the two of us at the moment.  What I really want to know is if he did the re-word correctly.  Was he supposed to have pushed his new commit up from the History right-click menu?

Comment: Well, as you saw, the push of the new commit was rejected, because he was rewording a commit that was already pushed. So he did not do the reword "correctly" in the sense that he should have done the reword before he pushed.